# Truncate long line and append indicating symbol

Tags: linux, text-processing, csv

I have sample:

```
"this is a long title must in a doule quotes"     this_is_a_solid_long_line_without_space_or_tabs
```

`"this is a long title must in a doule quotes"` is a long line in double quotes that need to truncate.

`this_is_a_solid_long_line_without_space_or_tabs` is a long line that does not 
contain `space` or `tab` that need to trunate.

two items separated by `tab`

expected output:

```
"this is a long title mus..>      this_is_a_solid_long_li..>
```

that `..>` indicate a long line.

Comment: So both "long line"s are on a single line in the input file? What are the rules for truncation? Are you truncating to 25 characters if there is a `"`, and 23 if there is no `"`? How does the presence of a space of tab affect this calculation?

Comment: Yes, they're both on a single line, we can specify how many character in filter, `tab` and `space` between both to easy filter the first one that start with `"` and end with `"`, the second one after `"`.* and `\s` I guess.

Comment: Something like `sed 's/^("?.{,25}).*("?)/\1\2..>/'`? (Not sure about the escaping, currently on mobile so can't test…)

Comment: With `-r`: `sed -r 's/^("?.{,25}).*("?)/\1\2..>/'` it gives: `"this is a long title must..>`, where's `\2`?

Comment: `\2` is empty because `.{,25}` is greedy. Not sure off-hand if sed supports non-greedy matching. Try `.{,25}?`.

Comment: Yes, it's greedy, `sed -r 's/^("?.{,25}).*".*\s(.?{,25}*)$/\1..>\t\2..>/'` gives: `"this is a long title must..>   this_is_a_solid_long_line_without_space_or_tabs..>` that `\2` can't be filtered out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the columns in the original file are tab-delimited:

```
$ awk -v len=20 -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } 
      { for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if (length($i)>len) $i = substr($i,1,len-3) "..>" }; 1' file
"this is a long t..>    this_is_a_solid_l..>
```

This goes through the columns on each line and if any column is longer than the user-supplied `len` variable, it is truncated.  The truncation ensures that the length of the column, including the indicator (`..>`), is exactly `len` characters.

If the columns are separated by multiple spaces or tabs (at least two), and if you are using GNU `awk`, then you may instead use

```
awk -v len=20 -F '[[:blank:]]{2,}' 'BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
    { for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if (length($i)>len) $i = substr($i,1,len-3) "..>" }; 1' file
```

This still writes tab-delimited output.